# Copy values from dynamicly created inputs to text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bootstrap row with 3 columns. Each column have input. I have button "add row" which add another row with 3 column. Each input values are copying to textarea. But I have problem. I can copy values from only first row. How Can I copy values from all inputs? And second question, how Can I format output like this

Row1
data-1
data-2
data-3

Row2
data-4
data-5
data-6

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row inputs">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="szerokosc" class="entry" id="szerokosc_1" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="wysokosc" class="entry" id="wysokosc_1" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="dlugosc" class="entry" id="dlugosc_1" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button id="add">add row</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<textarea class="box" name="result" rows="5"> </textarea>

$('#add').click(function(){
$('.row.inputs:last').clone().insertAfter(".row.inputs:last").val('');
});
$("input").on('keyup',function() {
    var values = "";
    $("input:text").each(function(i) {
        var text=$(this).prev("label").text();
        values +=  (i > 0 ? "\n" : "") + this.value+ " "+text;
    });
    $("textarea").val(values);
});
```

Comment: why my answer isn't good ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

No to make the newly added inputs also trigger our `keyup`, change `$("input").on('keyup', function() {` to `$(document).on('keyup', "input", function() {`

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('.row.inputs:last').clone().insertAfter(".row.inputs:last");
  $('.row.inputs:last input').val("")
  console.log($(".row.inputs").length)
  if ($(".row.inputs").length == 2){
  $('.row.inputs:last .col-sm-4:last').css("float","left").after('<div><button style="margin-left: 20px" class="removeRow">remove row</button></div>')
  } 
    
});
$(document).on('keyup', "input", function() {
  updateTextarea()
});

$(document).on('click', ".removeText", function() {
  $(this).prev("input").val("")
  updateTextarea()
});

$(document).on('click', ".removeRow", function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").remove()
  updateTextarea()
});

function updateTextarea() {
  var values = "";
  $(".row.inputs").each(function(i) {
    values += "row" + (i + 1) + ": "
    $(this).find("input").each(function(x, e) {
      $(this).next("button").css("display", this.value.length > 0 ? "initial": "none")
      var text = $(this).prev("label").text();
      values += this.value + " " + text;
    })

    values += "\n"
  });
  $("textarea").val(values);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.removeText{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row inputs">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" name="szerokosc" class="entry" id="szerokosc_1" value="" /><button class="removeText">remove text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" name="wysokosc" class="entry" id="wysokosc_1" value="" /><button class="removeText">remove text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" name="dlugosc" class="entry" id="dlugosc_1" value="" /><button class="removeText">remove text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button id="add">add row</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <textarea row="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes!! But it would be nice if new rows don't have any values.

Comment: @MMPL1 Updated, take a look

Comment: hell yeah! This is what I looking for. I have another favor. Can you add button "remove inputs" next to each row added dynamicly? I also want to delete this values from textarea.

Comment: @MMPL1 Like this?

Comment: @MMPL1, have a look to my answer.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen almost! I want to remove this input too. For example

input input input [delete]

when I click on [delete] I remove whole row with 3 input fields and values from textarea

Comment: @MMPL1 Updated with a remove row button

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen I made small visualisation. Optionally remove button can be below inputs in row
    http://i.imgur.com/jzGlALu.jpg

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen last fix and we got it! First row can't be deleted. Only second row, third row etc. And please remove button "remove text".

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, +1 for your effort.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen I tried implement this into my website. I have one problem. I can't hide remove row button on first row. How Can I do this? https://pastebin.com/jBT0QTkk

Comment: @MMPL1 in my code there is no remove row button for the first row.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen ok, my bad. But know there's another fix to do :D When I click add row I have one remove row button. When I add another row I have 2 remove row buttons etc. Quick look - http://i.imgur.com/z1WB7SP.png How to find where to fix it?

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen we got it! Thank you so so so much! Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **event delegation** for elements which were added **dynamically**.

You should bind click event handler using `.on()` method.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Read more about event delegation [here.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
  var anotherRow=$('.row.inputs:eq(0)').clone();
  anotherRow.append('<div class="col-sm-3"><button class="removeText">remove text</button></div>');
  anotherRow.find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val('');
  });
  anotherRow.insertAfter(".row.inputs:last");
});
$(document).on('keyup',"input",function() {
    var values = "";
    $("input:text").each(function(i) {
        var text=$(this).prev("label").text();
        values +=  (i%3 ==0 ? "\n row"+(i/3)+" " :"") + this.value+ " "+text;
    });
    $("textarea").val(values);
});
$(document).on('click',".removeText",function() {
    $(this).closest('.inputs').remove();
    var values = "";
    $("input:text").each(function(i) {
        var text=$(this).prev("label").text();
        values +=  (i%3 ==0 ? "\n row"+(i/3)+" " :"") + this.value+ " "+text;
    });
    $("textarea").val(values);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row inputs">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="szerokosc" class="entry" id="szerokosc_1" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="wysokosc" class="entry" id="wysokosc_1" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="dlugosc" class="entry" id="dlugosc_1" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button id="add">add row</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<textarea class="box" name="result" rows="5"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Sweet! Can you add "remove row" next to created row? Also I want to delete values from this row from textarea

Comment: we nearly there! First row shouldn't have option to delete. Only second, third etc. small visualization - http://i.imgur.com/jzGlALu.jpg

Comment: @MMPL1, have a look now.